# How to create a one to many relationship using ADO.NET Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I am struggling with an issue and from what I've seen none of the propsed solutions work.

Basically I have two classes:

```
public class Role
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ActionType
{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> AllowedRoles { get; set; }

    public ActionType()
    {
        this.AllowedRoles = new List<Role>();
    }  
}
```

I would like for EF to force  an association table in the DB, where the FK is used to reference the one to many relation. Somehow code first creates a table for my `Role` where a column `ActionType_ID` is added. Not useful of course when more `Role`s are added to one `ActionType`. A `DBUpdateExcpetion` is being trown.

Any thoughts on how I should resolve this? The point being that classe Role doesn't refer to ActionType, since this is not useful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you really trying to do? At the moment you can add more `Role`s to single `ActionType` but single `Role` cannot be added to multiple `ActionType`s. Do you want that as well?

In such case you are not doing one-to-many association but many-to-many. Only many-to-many relation uses junction (association) table. One-to-many relation indeed means that dependent entity (the one on many side) has FK to principal entity. The simplest approach is defining navigation property in Role as well:

```
public class Role
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ActionType> ActionTypes { get; set; } 
}

public class ActionType
{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> AllowedRoles { get; set; } 
}
```

If you don't want to have navigation property in Role you must use fluent API to describe the relation.

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ActionType>()
                    .HasMany(a => a.AllowedRoles)
                    .WithMany();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, the last proposed scenario works like a charm. It seems like I have to dive in this fluent API.